# Keras network with loss evaluated on entire dataset rather than element-wise

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to use a keras neural network to generate a set of outputs that are evaluated in **a group** to determine performance (not element-wise). This would differ from the typical loss function like mse, which calculates an individual loss value per element. The reason that this method is desired is because the performance can't be understood by looking only at singular elements and there is no "ideal" output to compare to, just a "score" that ought to be minimized or maximized.
I have been attempting to make this work using a custom loss function and some generic Dense layers in keras, but it is highly unstable.
Is there a better/preexisting method? (See pseudocode of current setup in below image)

[image: Pseudocode]

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:
It wasn't until I typed this out that I realized I was describing the need for a [Reinforcement Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) network, not a typical Supervised Learning network like I had been working with.

Comment: That's interesting. I would have expected you wanted to change your `batch_size` when you call `model.fit(...)`. If you want your loss calculated on several examples at once, increase the batch_size.